# Matlab to C porting

Tags: c, matlab

I'm working onto several routines that i've to port from Matlab to Ansi-C. Since i'm not a Matlab veteran i try to ask to you about some cryptic rows.

**1)**

```
%Matlab
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-k:k,-k:k);
```

Supposing that k == 3, the above line is supposed to make TWO Matrix (X and Y) With the following aspect:

```
   [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
   [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
   [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
X= [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
   [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
   [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
   [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]


   [-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3]
   [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2]
   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
Y= [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
   [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
   [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2]
   [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3]
```

is this correct?

**2)** The following statement, i suppose that create a submatrix, is there any efficent way to convert it in regular C?

```
I = A(iMin:iMax,jMin:jMax,:);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi valvoline! Did Drayton not answer your question sufficiently? Just wondering why you didn't click to accept his answer...?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes :-)

2) I guess you have to loop over the second and third index (lets call them j and k) of the array and copy each of the ranges of the form A(iMin:iMax,j,k) manually.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question, there is no shortcut if you don't want to use any other libraries. The operation is called [array slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) so Google might help if you search for a C library that might offer something similar.

Also, if you don't mind writing it in C++ instead of C, you might take a look at http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax There are various other linear algebra libraries on C and C++ I'm sure, but armadillo seems to be closest to what MATLAB can offer.

Comment: Hi uston, thank for you response. However, i need to use C, since i'm programming for an embedded board that have only a subportion of ansi-c.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, but if you are writing your own code, there is no reason to waste all the space from the duplication. A X-Vector and Y-Vector as such:

```
int X[] = {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3};
int Y[] = {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3};
```

will allow you to access the same information but without the memory waste (which might be a big issue on an embedded system). Rather than access `X(i,j)` and `Y(i,j)`, you access `X[i]` and `Y[j]`.

2) Depending on how large your arrays are, there may be more efficient options than accessing element by element. Assuming you are storing your array in row-major order (i.e.

A_1,1 A_1,2 A_1,3 ... A_1,n

A_2,1 ...

is stored A_1,1 A_1,2 A_1,3 ... A_1,n A_2,1 ...

You can copy a slice by the following:

```
/* Initialization code omitted, let A be n x m */
/* Also assuming that [i/j][Max/Min] are zero indexed */
int i, diff_i, diff_j;
diff_i = iMax - iMin;
diff_j = jMax - jMin;

size_t stride = sizeof(YOUR DATA TYPE HERE) * (1 + diff_j);

/* I = A(iMin:iMax,jMin:jMax,:); */
for(i = 0; i <= diff_i; i++){
    memcpy(&I[i*diff_j],&A[i*m + jMin],stride);
}
```

This will grab a row at a time rather than a single element at a time.